TUSB4020BIPHPRQ1 connection to upstream USB Hub
I am designing a 2 channel USB Hub board using the TUSB4020BIPHPRQ1 from Texas Instruments.
This chip will be connected to the USB port of another hub upstream (USB2514 from Microchip).
The USB2514 has an overcurrent flag input associated to each downstream device to detect over current situations. So does the TUSB4020BIPHPRQ1 as well (for its downstream devices).
How would the USB2514 hub detect overcurrent situations with the TUSB4020BIPHPRQ1 hub that is connected downstream?
Thanks,
